# PHP Nette Throws Error When Someone Submits Form

Tags: php, smtp, nette

I get this error whenever someone submits the form:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Nette\Mail\SendException: Unable to send email.

Here is my code:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
  $values = $form->getValues();

  $mail = new \Nette\Mail\Message;
  $mail->setFrom('asdr1@yahoo.com')
          ->addTo('asdr1@yahoo.com')
          ->setSubject('New contact')
          ->setHtmlBody('Hi<br> you\'ve got new message.<br> from: ' . $values['name'] . '<br> email: ' . $values['email'] . '<br> Message:' . $values['message']);

  $mailer = new Nette\Mail\SendmailMailer();
  $mailer->send($mail);
```

how i set SMTP for gmail

```
public $defaults = [
        'smtp' => false,
        'host' => null,
        'port' => null,
        'username' => null,
        'password' =>  null,
        'secure' => null,
        'timeout' => null,
        'clientHost' => null,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`SendmailMailer` uses php function `mail()` and it has to be configured in `php.ini` to work, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Simplest way of using smtp with Nette is `SmtpMailer`

```php
$mailer = new \Nette\Mail\SmtpMailer($this->defaults);
```

Also don't forget to set correct configuration, gmail will not accept empty credentials. Something like:

```php
public $defaults = [
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'example@gmail.com',
    'password' =>  '****',
    'secure' => 'ssl',
];
```

Comment: thank you, the password is gmail password or the app password we generate after enable the two factor auth